# how to prompt user to break in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
package task;
import java.util.*;

public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter \"t\" to terminate.");
        for(;;){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i;
            double I = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            for(i = 0; i <= I; i++){
                System.out.println("Integer " + i);
                String a = input.next();
                if(a.equals("c")){
                    break;
                }   
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

I am having trouble in prompting the user to enter "t" to end the for loop. I basically want the for loop to print out every single positive integer, and when I decide to end, I enter "t".

If I could get some help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: "t" or "c"? Because you currently only test for `c`. Also, you have nested loops. If you want to break the outer loop, you need to label it.

Comment: Also each time your outer loop iterates, it creates new Scanner. Don't do it. create one scanner before loops and reuse it later inside loops.

Comment: Also some convention stuff: use `while(true)` instead of `for(;;)` and since `i <= I` anyway is always going to be true drop the `I` and simply use `for (int i = 0; ; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a do while instead of a for+break

**Do while :**

```
    System.out.println("Enter \"t\" to terminate.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pressed;
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        i=0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Integer " + i);
            pressed = input.next();
            i++;
        } while (!pressed.equals("t"));
    }
```

Note that you are not testing if the input is an integer.